# How can I choose which account to remain when merging user accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I'm trying to merge two of my accounts, and I tried to follow the standard procedure from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact)  (I need to merge user profiles).

I put on "my profile link" my main account (this one) and in "the other profile link", the other account that I have.
The only issue after I followed all the steps (with e-mail confirmation), was that the system announced that my main account is going to be deleted and everything from it will be moved to my "other" account.

Then I thought maybe I have to reverse the order, so I put my main account as  "other profile link" and even changed the order of the e-mail (in another ticket), yet for some reason, this account was about to be deleted no matter what I did.

This was about two days ago, so I tried once again, but now I'm receiving the confirmation e-mail for only one of my accounts. Well, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but can I get some assistance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot. We always merge accounts into the lower network account Id and there is no override for that, even for staff. If you'd prefer a particular display name to be kept, you should change it on the other account prior to completing a merge to make sure you aren't blocked from changing it for 30 days.

---

We've responded to your custom requests in our support system twice already, but never got any replies back from you. Please make sure you check the accounts you used to contact us to see if you can find those emails.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that, thanks alot! I just checked my spam e-mails now (I didn't know they will end up there) and yes you did respond. Haha, I thought I'm being ignored.